# installation SAP HANA VORA : Error dependencies : libgmp.so.3 missing

Tags: vora

When I install the file *rpm I get this error message :
"Problem: nothing provides libgmp.so.3()(64bit) needed by libmpc2-0.8.2-1.7.1.x86_64".

How can I import this library or resolve this dependencie ?

Thank you.

Comment: This issue occurs when I execute this command : "sudo zypper -n install tmp/*rpm".

Comment: to install the files rpm that have been contained in the file SLES11-compat-c++.tar

Answer (score 0):

These SAP Notes have instructions to install the compat libraries for SLES:

- compat libraries 4.7 as per SAP Note 2001528 https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002001528
- compat libraries 4.8 as per SAP Note 2228351 https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2228351

Both instruct to run

```
zypper install libgcc_s1 libstdc++6
```

Make sure you have the correct versions as documented in both Notes.